# Retrieving all records where a particular column value can be an item in a list in c# using EF DBSET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to do this for quite some time but not able to sort it out. Would appreciate if someone knows how to do this...

I am using EntityFramework and I want to retrieve all records from a Table called points where Description field matches any strings in a list...Kind of, try to do something like the below

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>();
db.Points.Where(m.Description IN someList)
```

How to achieve this in C# and EF with the right lambda expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>();
db.Points.Where(m => someList.Contains(m.Description))
```

Multiple Conditions:

```
db.Points
 .Where(m => someList.Contains(m.Description))
 .Where(m => m.someprop == true)
```

OR

```
db.Points
 .Where(m => someList.Contains(m.Description) && m.someprop == true)
```

Comment: Awesome !!! Thanks so much !!!

One small followup - how do you combine with another condition??? Like I want to check m=>m.someprop == true and the above condition ?

Comment: @PuneetGupta both ways above!